# Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, build-error

I was working on a resw file to enter my uwp app strings but after I finished the resw file when i wanted to build app it shows me the error that listed above :

**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v14.0\8.2\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(264,5): Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.**

after I excluded the file but it still shows this error ! 
What is this error & why i get this ?

Comment: With only this error message it's hard to say where the problem is. Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Please add further information... I think this error doesn't have to do with the resources file, seems like there's an erronous XAML page.

Answer (score 3):

This issue can be replicated referencing `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xaml.dll`

I've had the same problem, I don't know if my solution is applicable for all situations:

Look for `System.Xaml.dll` in you references and remove it

[image]

> This reference was added by `VS` without reason (I think)

`Clean, rebuild and run` your project.

If you get this error:

> CSC : error CS5001

Just follow this tutorial by [Marius Bancila](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2014/12/23/app-xaml-requires-an-applicationdefinition-build-action/)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same "WMC9999" error reported in the output window: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v14.0\8.2\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(264,5): Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."

It turned out to be a silly copy-and-paste mistake in the XAML. Notably, instead of being:

```
<Page x:Class="MyAppNamespace" ...
```

it was:

```
<Page x:Class="namespace MyAppNamespace" ...
```

(I just pasted the "namespace" keyword in the x:Class attribute's value, followed by a space).
To solve the problem, just ensure that your XAML is correct!

Hope this can help...

Comment: This was exactly the issue that I was experiencing.  Thanks to this answer I was able to solve this very unhelpful error report very quickly.  I really appreciate you taking the time to post this here; thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing UWP and meet this error, it can be a mistake of referencing System.Windows.Form (somehow by automatically correcting Alt-Enter is root-evil).
Remove this from your references list and build your solution again.